# Record video in Landscape always even device rotating (Landscape->Portrait->Landscape)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avcapturesession

I need to record video always in landscape mode even my device rotating (Portrait->Landscape->Portrait ).

To take angle is simple, im using hyroscope. My problem is to record video in landscape always. Any advices needed.

Im using `AVCaptureSession` to video rec. AVMutablecomposition? I dont know what to use...
help me,please

Answer (score 1):

Why not forcing your Controller  to be only in landscape mode ?

You can do it like this :

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate 
{
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

Comment: but when I watch video from cameara roll  it rotated. must be paralel to horizont

Comment: spec: When we use native ios camera rec. When we record video and rotate device video on screen not rotates to, but when we watch him, video rotates on player. I want to make something like we are recording video(video recordes and not rotated when device rotating and in player video not rotates to,it paralell to horizont)

Comment: Ok got it. you've got to lock the rotation when the user start recording a video. I think you should allow rotating while you're not recording.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
@implementation PortraitViewController
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DisplayAlternateView" sender:self];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }
}
```

Also have look on the Apple's docs [**HERE**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html) for detail rotation implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before starting to record a video:

```
let videoDataOuputConnection = videoFileOutput.connection(with: .video)
videoDataOuputConnection!.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.landscapeLeft
```